# Triangle equality in a Riemannian manifold implies "geodesic colinearity"?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $(M,g)$ be a **non-complete** Riemannian manifold. Assume $p,q,r\in M$ satsify:
$d(p,q)=d(p,r)+d(r,q)$, where $d$ is the Riemann distance function induced by the metric $g$. 
I am trying to find the most general assumptions which imply existence of a length minimizing geodesic between $p,q$ which passes through $r$.

**Partial Results:**

**A necessary & sufficient condition:** There exist (normalized) minimizing geodesics $\alpha,\beta$ from $p$ to $r$ and from $r$ to $q$.

**Sufficiency:**

Look at the concatenation $\gamma = \beta * \alpha $. Then $L(\gamma)=L(\alpha)+L(\beta)=d(p,r)+d(r,q)=d(p,q)$, so $\gamma$ is a piecewise smooth minimizing path, hence it is a geodesic which passes through $r$. (by corollary 3.9 page 73 do-Carmo Riemannian Geometry).

In particular, if the manifold is complete the answer is positive.

**Necessity:** Follows since for any minimizing geodesic, any sub-segment of it is also minimizing.

In particular, this means that the assertion is false for $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash{(0,0)}$.

Are there any non-complete manifodls for which it is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are non-complete manifolds for which this is true. Any convex proper open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with its Euclidean metric, for example.

The condition that there exists a minimizing geodesic between any two points in $M$ is called [geodesic convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_convexity).